# all required agent virtual machines are not currently deployed on host 'hostname'

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere

Getting the above error on a virtual machine. Powered it off, added more RAM, tried to power it on again. Now I get this error

[image]

Does anyone know what this means or how to fix it?

Comment: Migrate VM to another host and try to power it up.

Comment: Done, and it powers on fine now. But still no idea what this error means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, that it is a known issue on VMware as I found out during to answer this Question, its listed as KB 50121349 on VMware

> Symptoms Powering on the NSX Manager fails. vCenter Server was unable
> to find a suitable host to power on the following virtual machines for
> the reasons listed below
>
> - DRS cannot find a host to power on or migrate the virtual machine
> - All required agent virtual machines are not currently deployed on host 'hostname'
>
> Resolution To resolve this issue:
>
> Restart the hostd processes on the affected ESXi host by running this
> command:
>
> /etc/init.d/hostd restart
>
> Restart the vCenter Agent processes on the affected ESXi host by
> running this command:
>
> /etc/init.d/vpxa restart

[Reference of Text from Above, added here to save it for the future in case if removal](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/50121349)

But Moving to a other host fix this also :-)

Answer (score 0):

I saw this issue after upgrade to vSphere 6.7 U1 from 6.5 U1.
Reregistering NSX and resolve its issues also resolved the mentioned error.